# Extract textbook names and journal articles from various syllabi

Tags: r, text, nlp, text-extraction

I am trying to extract textbook names, and other journal articles in syllabi collected from various courses using R. My basic assumption is that most of these will be in some kind of a citation format (e.g. APA, MLA, etc). While I can try to create regex-s to extract this information, I was wondering if anyone has tried to do this before, or if an R package exists that I may be able to use to extract this information from differently formatted text. 
Below are two examples of the syllabi that I am working with. In Sample 1, the book name is not in a citation format, but in sample 2, it is in a citation format. Both samples have been truncated to meet stackoverflow character limits.

> SAMPLE 1:
>   "ABC State University  ARTS 3366 Intermediate Digital Photography  Fall 2015 JCM 4127 T/TH 2­4:30 pm   Lecturer: John Smith Office Hours: T/TH prior to and after class Email: ​johnsmith@abcstate.edu Alternate email: johnsmith@gmail.com Prerequisites​: ARTS 3364 ­ Introduction to Digital Photography  Course Description & Objectives:  This course is designed to expand and build on the skills and knowledge acquired in Introduction to Digital Photography.  This course builds on the skills and knowledge acquired in Introduction to Digital Photography. Specifically, we will use the history, critical analysis, and production of photography books to: (1) explore the complexities of the medium in social, political, and aesthetic contexts; (2) develop more advanced and conceptually driven photography work; (3) work toward a greater understanding of how photography books function as self­contained art, cultural, and political objects; (4) learn how to choose subject matter and continually explore, experiment, and refine our work. The final outcomes ofthe class will be the creation of an on­demand book and an accompanying folio of fine prints.  We will use digital cameras, inkjet printers, Adobe Photoshop, Lightroom, and Macintosh computers in this course. Through lectures, discussions and readings, we will explore and discuss historical trends in traditional (analog) photography, as well as emerging practices in contemporary digital imaging. This will serve as a foundation to help determine the approach, subject matter, and style of the work created for class. In addition to refining these skills, students will also address the practical and theoretical roles of digital imagery.   The course objective will be to focus on technical, aesthetic, and conceptual growth of a student’s endeavors in the digital medium. This course requires the completion of:  all assignments (on time), participation in all group critiques and completion of a Twelve to Fifteen image final portfolio of prints or equivalent, and three projects throughout the semester.   Requirements:  Coursework: This course requires the completion of:  all assignments (on time), participation in all group critiques and completion of a 12­15 image final portfolio of prints or equivalent, the creation of a book printed with an on demand printing service, as well as making new photographs consistently throughout the entire semester.  Suggested (not required)Books:  Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5 Book, The: The Complete Guide for Photographers   By Martin Evening Published Jun 30, 2013 by Adobe Press  The Photographer’s Playbook 307 Assignments and Ideas Edited by Jason Fulford and Gregory Halpern  Published by Aperture   On Being a Photographer: A Practical Guide ​ ​by David Hurn and Bill Jay Local Stores:"
>
> SAMPLE 2:"Physical Education Activity ProgramHealth & Fitness Strength TrainingKINE 198-837Instructor: JANE DOE Office: PEAP 230Office Hours: By appointmentPhone: (000) 000-0000E-Mail: jdoe@xyz.edu A. Activity Instructor: Jane DoeOffice: PEAP 250Office Hours: By appointmentClass Time: Thursday 2:20 pmPhone: (000) 000-0000Email: jdoe@xyz1.edu Class Meeting Site: PEAP 117B. Activity Instructor: Jane Doe Phone:Office: PEAP 239Email: jdoe@xyz1.eduOffice Hours: Thursday 10:00 am – 12:00 pmClass Time: Thursday 2:20 pmClass Meeting Site: PEAP 118C. Activity Instructor: John doe Office: PEAP 250/Doe 213KOffice Hours: Tuesday 1:00-2:00 pmClass Time: Thursday 2:20 pmPhone:Email: johndoe@xyz.eduClass Meeting Site: PEAP 120Attire: Proper clothes and shoes designed specifically for strength training on activitydays.Required Materials:Bounds, L., Agnor, D., Darnell,G., & Brekken Shea, K. (2012). Health & Fitness: AGuide to a Healthy Lifestyle (5th edition). Dubuque, IA: Kendall/Hunt Publishing Co.ISBN 978-1-4652-0712-8Cissik, J. (2001). The Basics of Strength Training (3rd Edition). McGraw-Hill,Primus Custom PublishingCourse Description:Health and Fitness is intended for the student who is seeking knowledge and practicalapplication of wellness choices to their life. The course consists of two components,lecture and activity. Students will meet face-to-face one day per week for the activityportion of the class and work approximately the equivalent of one day per week onlinewith lecture materials. The lecture portion will cover current health issues includingmental and physical health, nutrition, human sexuality, communicable and noncommunicable diseases, use and abuse of drugs, and safety. The activity portion willconsist of 14 class days and cover basic knowledge and techniques of strength trainingand improving the individual’s fitness through the utilization of this knowledge.Course Rationale:Research indicates that daily health/fitness related behaviors enhance learning anddetermine the quality and longevity of our life."

Comment: From what I know/have seen (edx, McGill, MIT), there is no standard format and there aren't any R libraries to extract this info. You'd have to create your own regex patterns. However if it's all from the same source, I guess there would at most 2-3 different formats and you could create functions for each of those formats and then one for identifying which function to call. I did the same when extracting data from some html sources.

Comment: Thanks @Gautam! That's kind of what I wanted to know. Unfortunately, it's not just 2-3 different formats. I think I can create regex-s based on different citation formats, and proceed from there. I will not be able to extract everything, but should be able to get quite a few.